# python. как правильно сгенерировать guidnumber в ldap

Tags: python, linux, ldap

Всем привет. Есть ли совсем правильная методика генерации gidnumber в ldap ? если нет то как правильнее генерировать gidnumber в зависимости от uid пользователя, чтобы gidnumber, для :

```
cn=someuser,ou=testsubgroup,o=testgroup,dc=test,dc=rdi
```

и

```
cn=newsomeuser,ou=testsubgroup,o=testgroup,dc=test,dc=rdi
```

был одинаковым,но не совпадал с :

```
cn=anothernewsomeuser,ou=testsubgroup,dc=test,dc=rdi
```

?

Comment: У вас же вопросы по AD, а не по LDAP-у в целом, так? Что такое `guidnumber`? Скорее `gidNumber`? Какой критерий отличия `anothernewsomeuser` от `someuser / newsomeuser`?

Comment: извиняюсь , действительно gidnumber. Критерий отличия то что первые два пользователя лежат в ou=testsubgroup,o=testgroup,dc=test,dc=rdi, а третий в   ou=testsubgroup,dc=test,dc=rdi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это всего лишь отличия в DN-ах записей, к идентификатору группы `gidNumber` это никакого отношения не имеет. `gidNumber` у всех юзеров может быть одинаковый, а может быть разный, и зависит от того, в качестве чего вы выберете `основную группу` для юзера следуя логике вашего каталога.

Например, есть группа `sales` с `gidNumber` 1002, и есть группа `managers` (1003). Первым двум юзерам в качестве основной группы начисляется `sales`, третьему юзеру - `managers`. Какой при этом DN у этих юзеров - не важно. Логически `менеджер` может находиться тут `ou=testsubgroup,o=testgroup,dc=test,dc=rdi`, а может и тут - `ou=testsubgroup,dc=test,dc=rdi`.

**Как генерировать gidNumber?**

Как хотите. Создаете группу `sales` и назначаете `gidNumber` равный 1, или 100, или 1000. Создаете следующую группу `managers` и назначаете номер 2, или 101, или 1001, и т.д. А при создании юзера начисляете ему gid соответствующей группы.

Всё.